# PHP and MySQL special characters error

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to make an article poster that works perfectly until I put special characters in the html form (like `;,!` etc.). I Googled it and found something about the table collation (which is `utf8_unicode_ci` by default).

I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` into the header file and `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8')` after connection to the database. Also the form has `accept-charset="utf-8"` attribute.

Here is what happens after sending the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{
    $articleTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $articleText = $_POST['text'];
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];

    $currentDateMySQL = date("Y.m.d");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (title, text, owner, date_added) VALUES ('$articleTitle', '$articleText', '$name', '$currentDateMySQL')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result === false)
    {
        $color = "red";
        $infoText = "Could not insert your information into the database. Error number: <b>" . mysqli_errno($conn) . "</b>. :( Try again.";
    }
    else
    {
        $color = "green";
        $infoText = "Succesfully writen the article into the database. :)";
    }
}
```

Also the given error number is `1064`. There is no error in the SQL code, it works perfectly without special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need do escape every input you trying to insert into a database otherwise you risking sql-injection attacks:

```
$articleText = mysql_real_escape_string($articleText);
```

Also you shouldn't use native sql directly anymore, it is deprecated. You should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: it escapes special characters

Comment: I use mysqli not mysql but I do not use PDO

Comment: And thank you! That's how I did at registration. I forgot. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your table collation after creation, it does not mean your *column collation* does match.

All of the following charsets should match so that your data is inserted correctly:

- column charset collation
- connection charset

Even better, to have the same charset everywhere:

- defaut charset
- database charset
- table charset
- column charset
- connection charset

Comment: Thank you but the answer was to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. :)